# remove descriptions from pie chart

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I'm trying to get a pie chart in palantir workshop and group-by column names will appear on pie chart. Is there any way to remove them from the pie chart as I can see them in the legend as well. I don't want to get rid of my legend.

[image]

[image: pie chart setting]